# Cannot locate code OpenCart 2.2 shop

Tags: opencart, google-tag-manager, opencart2.x

I am trying to implement Google Tag Manager on my OpenCart store but have run into a strange problem.

This is the second time I'm trying to install GTM, and that is why when you go to my website www.eparhija.com and check out the home page source you can see a code snippet of the previous GTM implementation.

Now the problem is that I have removed that code snippet in the file it was located (header.tpl), but it is still visible on the website.

What could be the problem? Why is the code still there when it is removed in the file? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whenever you enable / disable or delete a modification you need to click the refresh button to rebuild your modification cache!

Comment: @MojtabaSabeti I did not do it trough the modifications, I just inserted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove it from `default` theme when you are using `customtheme`?

In catalog/view/theme -- if you have a folder other than `default`, also remove the code from the corresponding header.tpl file as well.

Comment: Hi. No, I'm not using a custom theme only the default one.

Comment: Do you have a page cache enabled?  Did you refresh the page (not just type the address, but force your browser to 'refresh')?

Comment: I just checked the code and it seems to be gone. I didn't do anything, it seems to have resolved itself. Thanks for input.